# ImportError: cannot import name api - Error Configuring aws_cli on centos 7

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I successfully installed aws using `pip install awscli --upgrade --user`. However, when I'm trying to `aws configure` or `aws --version`, I'm getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/aws", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('aws==0.2.5', 'console_scripts', 'aws')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 378, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2566, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2260, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aws/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from fabric import api as fab
ImportError: cannot import name api
```

My System details are as follows

```
Python 2.7.5
pip 18.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64
```

Path Variable is set to `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib:/opt/gradle/gradle-4.7/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/root/bin`

Comment: Seems like some issue with python2.7 Fabric module. I added `import fabric` and commented out all `from fabric import ...` statements and the issue is resolved. Though, I'm still clueless what went wrong? I commented out -                                         
`#from fabric import api as fab
#from fabric import state as fab_state
#from fabric.main import find_fabfile, load_fabfile, parse_arguments`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `aws` package in PyPI is not AWS's official CLI client but rather an older unmaintained library that used to interface with AWS and is now broken. AWS's official CLI client is `awscli`. Therefore if you `pip install aws` instead of `pip install awscli` you will run into the issue above.

The solution is to first run `pip uninstall aws` then run `pip install awscli`.

Comment: Helped for me, thanks!
See that https://pypi.org/project/aws/ not very often updating. Is it not supported anymore?

Comment: The author, Tomi Pajunen, should deprecate it

Comment: @code_monk +1 this is a dangerous name-squatting issue at this point

Comment: @ColinD I'm sure AWS has been trying to reach Tomi for some time now.

Answer (score 1):

Error with import if fabric submodules. Commented from fabric import .. statements and added import fabric. Not sure, if this is originally an issue but, resolved my problem. Please refer my comment on my question.

Comment: Can you please mark the answer from @CognizzantApe telling you to install [`awscli`](https://pypi.org/project/awscli/) instead of [`aws`](https://pypi.org/project/aws/) as accepted ?
I ran today into the same problem, and I'm pretty sure that was the source of the problem you had, given that the traceback you provided matches [the source code of that package in Github](https://github.com/eofs/aws/blob/479cbe27a9f289b43f32f8e3de7d048a4a8993fe/aws/main.py#L7), which seems to not have been maintained over the last 6 years.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to first run this code:

```
pip uninstall aws
```

Then run this one:

```
pip install awscli
```